# How to secure an appointment for Polish Schengen type C business visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, poland

I am struggling to secure an appointment from **last 1 week**. Is there a specific time period under which appointments slot are reserved?

Is there any other way of securing appointment with Polish consulate.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could not arrange a meeting at a Polish consulate because they seem to be working limited services/not working at all for non-emergency because of Covid. I would suggest calling the number for a particular consulate and trying to raise it as an emergency.